Chord definition misunderstanding
According to wikipedia's definition of chord (aeronautics), chord is a straight line that connects trailing edge to minimum radius point of leading edge.
What is so important about point of minimum radius that makes it the defining factor, or point to pass through, for chord definition? Why isn't chord, the line that defines longest distance from trailing edge to leading edge? That is the distance one giant caliper would measure on any wing?
It seems one slight modification to an airfoil can lead to massive chord angle variation with relation to that airfoil, while aerodynamic behaviour does(?) not look that much affected.

(two almost identical airfoils with minimal leading edge radius at various locations, resulting in large chord deviation. bottom is superposition of both)
If angle/line of zero lift of an airfoil looks useful for setting relative incidences between wing fuselage and horizontal stabilizer,
and the distance one giant caliper would measure looks useful -or seems the relevant value to pick- in order to define projected wing area,
I don't understand aeronautical chord's purpose and practical use.

It says the leading edge "may" be defined by the minimum radius of the leading edge.  How you choose to define it would make a difference in very curved turbine blade the article includes to illustrate this point, but I don't think it makes much difference in figures you use above.

"Minimum radius" is doubtful, for exactly the reason you demonstrate.  A more useful definition of LE is the forwardmost streamwise point, but that begs the definition of streamwise.  I haven't found anything authoritative though.

The definition of the "chord-line" is based on the leading and trailing edge as defined by the "mean camber line".

mean camber line - The locus of points halfway between the upper and lower surfaces [of the airfoil] measured perpendicular to the mean camber line itself. The most forward and rearward points of the mean camber line are the leading and trailing edges, respectively.
chord line - The straight line connecting the leading and trailing edges of the airfoil.
chord - the precise distance from the leading to trailing edge measured along the chord line.

From Introduction to Flight, John D. Anderson, Jr, McGraw-Hill, Copyright 1985, 1978. (Text from Aerospace Engineering curriculum, Texas A&M University)
To answer your question "What is the purpose of the chord line?", it is used to define the angle of attack seen by the airfoil. Which is defined as the angle between the relative wind and the chord line. In other words, it is an airfoil parameter (among others) used to describe an airfoil and characterize its performance.

You should consult Wikipedia with a healthy dose of skepticism.
Not that it isn't useful, but being the work of humans means that mistakes creep in from all sides. The chord definition is an example.
Normally, chord is the connection between the most forward part of the airfoil nose and the tip of the trailing edge, so your caliper method is as good as it gets on an uncambered airfoil. NACA Report 460, which published the original NACA 4-digit airfoil design method in 1933, only defines chord as

… the chord is taken along the x axis from 0 to 1 …

and what the x axis is can be seen in figure 1:

However, it gets more messy when camber is introduced: Now the chord line runs from the center of the circle inscribed into the nose radius to the trailing edge and is extrapolated until it connects with the airfoil contour:

This worked when airfoils were designed using simple equations, starting from a camber line and adding a thickness distribution. Since maybe 80 years, the design starts with a desired pressure distribution, with the contour only the result of that distribution, so there is no circle with a constant nose radius to start with. Pragmatically, we fall back to connecting the most forward and rearward part to find chord.

I don't understand aeronautical chord's purpose and practical use.

It is part of the wing geometry parameters. The precise angle and length is less important if its definition is used consistently. In the end, windtunnel or numerical simulation will give you the angle of the wing at which the desired lift is achieved, and its numerical value is of secondary importance.

To build up an airfoil, the classical way is to first draw the camber line (red) and then, along its length, circles with a radius corresponding to half the local thickness (grey). Then you connect the tops and bottoms of those circles with a smooth tangent (black).

And then there are airfoils like the GAW2, where the airfoil upper surface ends at z/c = -.0015, meaning the trailing edge end of the chord line is not on the airfoil and is just a random floating coordinate...

@ROIMaison In XFOIL, go into GDES and command NORM. A lot of coordinates are not cleaned up before put on a server.

Thanks for the pragmatic method, I see there are also 2 methods for drawing mean camber line. (both are called "camber line" but lead to different curves) First is the one described in David C. Rankin's answer and in your second graph. Second method is equidistant to upper and lower surfaces along Y axis, as seen here should one be preferred to the other?

@user721108 The canonical way is to draw the camber line and then to draw circles along its length with the appropriate radius to add the thickness distribution. Then you connect the tops and bottoms of those circles with a smooth line. This will only give you points perpendicular to the camber line when thickness does not change over chord.
